# How to close my App when an NFC tag is detected

Tags: java, android, nfc, alarmmanager, alarm

I am developing an alarm clock app that will allow you to turn off the alarm only if the app has detected an NFC tag. The tags I am using have nothing written to them I believe (when the phone detects the NFC tag it says "Empty tag"). Here is my code and was wondering if you could help! 
Android Manifest:

```
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
</intent-filter>
```

Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Wake Log");
        mWakeLock.acquire();
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.normal_alarm);

        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.isEmpty() == false){
            NewAlarm.time = "";
            NewAlarm.date = "";
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            finish();
        }
        playSound(this, getAlarmUri());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TAG_DISCOVERED` intent when used in the app's manifest is meant as a fall-back mechanism that is triggered only if no other app registered for more suitable NFC intents. So unless you develop for Android 2.3 (where `TAG_DISCOVERED` was the main NFC intent to use) you should avoid using this as the only NFC-related intent filter.

However, in your case (the app is already open as I understand it) you can skip intent filtering in the manifest completely. While your app is in the foreground, you should register for the [foreground tag dispatch system](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch).

Also note that

```
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.isEmpty() == false){
```

does not really make sense as `NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED` is a string constant that always contains the value `android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED`. So it will never be empty.